# IIS w3svc error

Tags: windows, http, iis, service

I am trying to start my website in IIS, whenever I try to start my website I get the following error

> Cannot start service w3svc on computer

I tried to start "World wide web publishing service", but I was unable to start it as it said:

> Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start

Meanwhile when I checked my log I found this error,

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service service depends on the HTTP service which failed to start because of the following error:
>   The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Please help me, I am badly caught with this error, I have spent a week researching this error but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Disabled is easy to check - launch `services.msc` and check to ensure that the `World Wide Web Publishing Service` isn't disabled. Dependencies could include `Windows Activation Service`, `RPC` etc.

Comment: My World Wide Web Publishing Service isn't disabled. I have re-checked it from services.msc

Comment: Do you see in the HTTP logs, usually found here: %systemroot%\system32\logfiles\HTTPERR

Comment: A similar error for me (caused using the VS2012 profiling tools) was solved using this post http://serverfault.com/questions/210903/windows-process-activation-service-wont-start-parameter-is-incorrect-visual

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1. Confirm that "Windows Management Instrumentation" is started and its start up type is set to `automatic`.
2. Also make sure the following dependency services are started for World Wide Web Publishing Service:

   - Windows Process Activation Service
   - Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
   - DCOM Server Process Launcher
   - RPC Endpoint Mapper.
3. Open regedit, navigate to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP]`:
   a) Double click on `Start` and change value data from `4`(disabled) to `3`(automatically).
   b) Delete `"NoRun"` key if this key exists.
4. *(warning: backup any IIS website configuration first)*. UN-install "Internet information Service" and "Windows process activation service(if it is already installed)" from "Turn windows feature on or off" and Restart your PC.
5. Type the below command in CMD and press enter:

   ```
    net start http
   ```

Now it will notify you that service is already running.

6. Re-install Internet information Service from "Turn windows feature on or off".
7. Start IIS and my websites are started now, no more "w3svc service is not running error."

Comment: I was having this same problem and restarting did not work. I also could not add a website to IIS, [I followed this 
 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792419/configuration-file-is-not-well-formed-xml-2) and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 20):

As for me - I just restarted the computer.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure these 2 services running and their startup type is automatic.If they disabled and not running right click on them and go to properties and change from there.

1. Windows process activation service
2. Worldwide web publishing service.

Comment: IIS is dependent on Windows Process Activation Service also, if that service is down then IIS will not start.

Answer (score 7):

Run cmd as administrator. Type `iisreset`. That's it.

Comment: Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Restart attempt failed.
The IIS Admin Service or the World Wide Web Publishing Service, or a service dependent on them failed to start.  The service, or dependent services, may had an error during its startup or may be disabled.

Comment: try to login through **Administrator** privilege account and do the same.

Comment: I couldn't restart because of the same reason

Answer (score 4):

Go to Task Manager --> Processes and manually stop the W3SVC process. After doing this the process should start normally when restarting IIS

Comment: Its more easier when using Process Explorer from sysinternals, the process is more easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, IIS suddenly stopped working, and after that Windows process activation service was unable to restart.

The solution to fix this was:

1. Find **WAS** service in the services tab of windows task manager
2. In context menu choose **Go to process**
3. Kill process (its name will be svchost.exe)
4. Restart Windows process activation service

Comment: Hi, I don't have that service listed. Do you know how I can install it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config which had an issue.
I had a "system.web" section in this file which was causing the problem. Removed the section and everything started working

Answer (score 1):

I have got same issue on my server. Follow below steps -

1. Open command prompt (run as administrator)
2. type IISReset and enter.

It works and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem after a windows update. Windows Process Activation Service is dependent service for W3SVC. First, make sure that Windows Process Activation Service is running. In my case, it was not running and when I tried to run it manually, I got below error.

**Windows Process Activation Service Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified**

The issue seems to be, that windows adds an incorrect parameter to the WAS service startup parameters. I fixed the issue using the following steps:

- Start regedit (just type it into start) Navigate to
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters
- Delete the NanoSetup variable. This variable is preventing WAS from starting
- Start the WAS service using task manager
- Now start the W3SVC service
- You can now start your website in IIS again

I found above WPA service solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283020/windows-process-activation-service-error-2the-system-cannot-find-the-file-speci) stack overflow thread.

Answer (score 1):

My **Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service** was disabled. I changed its startup to manual, started the service, and **then IISRESET worked**.

I also verified that the following dependent services were started in Services ([windows]+[r] services.msc):

- World Wide Web Publishing Service
- Windows Process Activation Service
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- DCOM Server Process Launcher
- RPC Endpoint Mapper
- Net.Msmq Listener Adapter
- Net.Pipe Listener Adapter
- Net.Tcp Listener Adapter
- Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service

I found this solution by going through all dependencies and child dependencies of the **World Wide Web Publishing Service** and making sure that each service was enabled and started.

To verify all services for yourself, do the following:

1. Open up **Services** (just search for it from the start menu in Windows 10)
2. Find the **World Wide Web Publishing Service**
3. Right click on the service and then click "**Properties**"
4. Click on the **Dependencies** tab
5. Go through each system component in the two boxes and verify that each service is started (in Services).
6. Repeat steps 3-5 for each of the dependencies' dependencies until you run out of child dependencies

[Service Properties - Dependencies Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3tUM.png)

Comment: This helped me a lot, turns out that the World Wide Web Publishing Service was not starting because the Windows Process Activation Service was not starting, when i tried to manually started it said that it could not start due to low space on the disk. Turns out that the server did not have any space left and i didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a rarer case, but...

If you are using a custom AppPool Identity configuration be sure to check the AppPool is running. It may be turned off because credentials are invalid (usually due to an expired password). Update your credentials and start the AppPool.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error. It turns out World Wide Web Publishing Service was disabled.

1. Click Start, type Services in the Search box, and then click Services.
2. Scroll until you find the World Wide Web Publishing Service that is stopped or disabled.
3. right-click the service, and then click Properties.
4. Click the Startup type list, and then click Automatic.
5. Click Apply, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve after:

1. Ctrl+Shift+Esc = To open **Task Manager**
2. In the "Processes" tab locate the "**IIS Worker Process**" and
   finish it!
3. Run on cmd as an administrator. Type **iisreset**.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this by simply executing the below command in PowerShell to kill/stop service and restart the IIS server

```
taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq w3svc"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me IISWorker Process was running in the background. Open Task Manager and killed the process. It worked