# Process with an ID #### is not running in vs 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am using IIS express to host an angularjs website that is collecting data from a webapi project within the same solution, also running under IIS express.

Whenever building the project I suddenly get following error:

***[IIS Express] Process with an ID #### is not running***

Any ideas what this problem might be and how to resolve it?

I have found a solution as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update). Nevertheless, I am just following instructions, it would also be great to understand what is happening...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process with an ID #### is not running in visual studio professional 2013 update 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all of the hidden .vs folders in your projects directoy.  Then restart visual studio and startup the debugger.