# Why project is not running giving error with id in visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Actually, my project is not running in visual studio 2015. When I click on run project then its giving error like below picture but its generate new id every time. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? Generally a reboot sorts. However if its persistent you may need to look here -

[process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update)

Comment: Thanks!, Now its working fine but as well as we need to remove `.vs` folder from solution main root.

Answer (score 1):

**step 1:** Delete bin and obj file on solution
[image]

**Step 2:** then close visual studio solution. 
**step 3:** Go folder and delete .vs folder.
[image]

**step 4:** next step run solution then you issue solve.