# Process with an ID #### not running

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application and when every time I start debugging, it throws an error

> Process with an ID (Random number every time) not running

in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Also in the output window, I see the following lines:

```
The program '[10144] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[10144] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What I tried:

- deleting .VS folder in the solution
- deleting IISExpress folder in `My Documents`
- changing project URL of the web site
- checking out 'Use 64bit version of IIS Express' in Tools > Options > Projects and solutions > Web projects
- deleting DEvelopmentServerPort, DevelopmentServerVPath and IISUrl in CSPROJ.
- repairing IISExpress from Add/Remove programs.
- like most of every solution I could find in StackOverflow and every where in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below solution.

1.Open your project file (csporj): Upload the project and right client the project file.

[image]

2.Find DevelopmentServerPort, if it contains and delete it then reload the project.

[image]

If this solution doesn't solve your issue, I suggest you could try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update/27155236#27155236).

---

Eidt

If your machine is 64bit, please go to Tools-> options -> projects and solutions:

### [image]

Could you please tell me this issue is only occured for current MVC application? If you start a new web application, it will work well.

If above solution doesn't solve your issue, I suggest you could try to use process monitor to find how IIS work.

Details about how to use process monitor, you could refer to below steps:

1. Download Procmon tool from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon
2. Open Procmon.exe  as Administrator.

3.Remove all the filters -> then Apply -> then OK

[image]

4.Make sure the telescope icon is shown as below, this indicates the capture is ongoing

[image]

5.Then reproduce the issue

[image]

6. Press CTRL + E to stop the trace capture
7. Press CTRL + S to save the log
8. Click "All events", Save log as "Native Process Monitor Format (PML)".

9.If this pml doesn't contain the importent data,you could share the pml to me to analysis it.

Comment: Tried that. It was mentioned in my list which I tried. But didn't work.