# Process with an Id of XXXX is not running | Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I've had this problem since this morning and have tried various options, but haven't found a solution to my problem yet.

The problem is that every time I want to start my Blazor web application I get this error message:

[image]

I tried several ways to solve this problem, however all I found was for IIS-Express with this problem.
I use several startup projects, and I don't find any solution for my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process with an ID #### is not running in visual studio professional 2013 update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update)

Comment: No, unfortunately not, the problem is that the project there is always started with IIS Express and I have tried the solutions there, but unfortunately they didn't work for me because I use several start projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I installed Visual Studio again it worked.

Comment: I updated the .NET SDK in my project before I updates Visual Studio. Updating VS solved the issue for me (for the next person having this issue: try this before reinstalling VS)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem this morning after updating the Microsoft packages in my WASM-project. Updating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer 6.0.8 to 6.0.9 resulted in the error mentioned. Updating to [.NET 6.0.109 SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/6.0.9/6.0.109.md) solved this. So in general: after updating the DevServer package you need to be sure you have the corresponding .NET SDK version (or higher) installed.

I'm using VS 2022 17.4.0 preview 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this steps:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to the sub-folder of Project's main folder.
3. Delete .vs folder and open project again in Visual Studio and RUN

if doesn't work
just click on build button in app bar in visual studio then click on Rebuild Solution and run

Answer (score 4):

Had an same issue when testing a Blazor app, it fixed after restored the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer from 6.0.8 to 6.0.5

Answer (score 4):

This solved it for me

https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1029540/solved-process-with-an-id-of-is-not-running

Open the .csproj file, and remove tags DevelopmentServerPort, DevelopmentServerVPath and IISUrl.

Comment: best solution, needs more votes

Comment: Other fixes, above, did not work but this solution did.  Since it results in the automatic assignment of a new port number, I suspect that this solution is no different than editing the project properties and just updating the port yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today; I updated my Blazor WASM project's nuget packages to the latest version but didn't update Visual Studio. After updating Visual Studio, this started working again. So try updating VS if you encounter this.

Comment: After trying the solutions above, this one actually fixed it. Don't overlook something this simple!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue this morning.
My project was targeting .NET Core 3.1 and I had installed the SDK.
After I installed the targeting pack, everything worked fine.

Go to the Visual Studio Installer and Modify your VS. Go to individual components and search for the .NET version you are using (Core 3.1 for me)
Make sure the targeting pack is installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Updating Visual Studio and the .NET SDK fixed it for me. I had SDK version 6.0.302 installed and updated to SDK version 6.0.400.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with code I downloaded from GitHub. The projects targetted .NET Core 3.1 which I hadn't installed. To solve, I double-clicked Properties in each project, and changed the Target framework to .NET 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

> "Process with an id xxxx is not running"

The error is quite misleading actually.
You should check in the VS Output window the exact details. In my case I had

> "The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.
> Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core"

Once I saw this error double checked the .NET versions of all my projects in the solution and turned out one of them is .NET Core 2.2, which is not present on my machine.

**The simple solution after I found out what is missing was to install the .NET Core 2.2 SDK and it worked!**

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the .vs folder as mentioned by others, but then went to the project properties and changed my framework version from 3.1 to 7.0, and rebuilt and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and once I updated Visual Studio, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case this applies to anyone...

On a fresh install of Windows 11, with .Net 8 installed.  The project I cloned from GitHub was configured to use .Net 6.  This version was not installed, so after installing the .Net 6 SDK, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
I restarted my computer and it worked, restarting is they key for windows :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for several reasons, but one that I didn't see mentioned here is a missing SDK that the project/solution is targeting.  Visual Studio 2022 will clue you in on the situation in the solution explorer menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting and misleading error. I have multiple .NET Framework 4.8 projects and none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I am yet to find a solution to this issue.