# IISRESET windows 10 (IIS 10) Access denied

Tags: iis-10

I'm just wondering, why I get error during an iisreset in my development machine.
When I execute the command in a Command Prompt some times it wokrs,sometimes it throws an Access Denied Error, and sometimes it throws a file not found exception.

[image]

If anyone finds a solution to this anoying problem, I would appreciate a hint how to get rid of it.

In the IIS I'm just hosting an .NET 4.6.1 MVC site.

Comment: Run cmd with admin right?

Comment: Yes... seen  the screenshot ?... It is running as administrator... that's why it is so strange

Comment: Did you look in event logs(app, security etc) for errors?

Comment: I have German OS with US-en language pack..so these errors appear in my eventlog: The WWW-Publishingdienst service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  ..AND ... The Windows-Prozessaktivierungsdienst service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).

Answer (score 10):

This stupid error happens randomly and was very annoying especially when you place iisreset inside a script and assume it will do its thing; took me a while to figure it out. It is not related to the service being stopped as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

The only thing I use now is:

> net stop W3SVC

and

> net start W3SVC

Haven't had a problem since then.

Comment: we are using Start-WebSite powershell command...maybee we just need to cycle w3svc entirely

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same error time ago. Running it in German too. Take a look at this article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/iis-reset-issue-restart-attempt-failed/ba-p/1031976

Judging from @Giorgi Nakeuri's question about the event logs. The "World Wide Web Publishing" (called only "WWW-Publishingdienst" in German) is very likely not running. You need to start it. The "Windows activity process service" fails because of the first one failing.

Comment: I think its running it happens intermitently Ill do iisreset and it shuts down then fails to start, do it again and it starts

Answer (score 2):

I think it says that he was unable to start the service, mainly due to a Problem with authorization. The solution of the problem can be provided in several different ways

1- Configuration causing the authorization error can be corrected
**applicationHost.config** with XML

2- This authorization can be revoked through the Windows register. Example approach here:

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/21036837/914284**

3- Machine configuration can be changed in accordance with this
permission. Please continue with the option that suits you :)

https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO1360

i hope it will resolve

Comment: if it was authorization wouldn't it fail every time? It only fails sometimes...fails when ran from a script or even from a cmd prompt

Comment: Above solution is right but the reason is that net command provides to reaching to main thread and it kills the process. That's handling the authenticity

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the machine name also helps in some scenarios:

```
iisreset %ComputerName%
```