# win10, iis10 can not start, w3svc service failed to start

Tags: iis

IIS is stoped, can't start.

When I checked services, the dependencies of w3svc are all running, but can't start w3svc.

```
C:\Users\lust4
λ sc qc W3SVC
[SC] QueryServiceConfig Success

SERVICE_NAME: W3SVC
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k iissvcs
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : World Wide Web 发布服务
        DEPENDENCIES       : WAS
                           : HTTP
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem

C:\Users\lust4
λ sc query WAS

SERVICE_NAME: WAS
        TYPE               : 30  WIN32
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Users\lust4
λ sc query HTTP

SERVICE_NAME: HTTP
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Users\lust4
λ sc query W3SVC

SERVICE_NAME: W3SVC
        TYPE               : 30  WIN32
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1066  (0x42a)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 2147943468  (0x8007042c)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

C:\Users\lust4
```

Below is the event log and says `the dependency service or group failed to start`:

```
+ <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7024</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-10-10T09:46:36.061057200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3129</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="720" ThreadID="4088" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>lust-sp</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">World Wide Web Publishing Service</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">%%2147943468</Data> 
  <Binary>570033005300560043000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Tried reinstall IIS (turn off iis feature => restart => turn on iis feature), not working. :(

Tried this : [IIS w3svc error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023622/iis-w3svc-error)

Answer (score 3):

find solution here, the cause of problem is win10 insider 14942 issue:

Insiders doing web development may find themselves their local intranet server unreachable, as service host separation will leave the IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3Svc) unable to start successfully. To fix this issue:

```
Run the following from an admin cmd line (or edit the registry accordingly):
    REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
    REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
Reboot the system, so that the W3Svc and WAS services share a service host process.
```

Read more at https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14942-for-pc/#ASMGhCcpJLY1BSKy.99