# Unable to start Windows Process Activation Service after trying the other solutions proposed

Tags: iis

After reading and trying the various solutions proposed, I am still unable to start the Windows Process Activation Service on my Wndows 10 professional system. I am getting error 2 initially. I create a tmp file as instructed but then I am receiving error 13 when I try to start the service. I have uninstalled and reinstalled IIS and WAS with no change. I am not certain what step to take next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Process Activation Service not starting - error 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998508/windows-process-activation-service-not-starting-error-13)

Comment: I have read the other solutions for this issue but they have not solved this issue for me.