# Windows Process Activation Service Error 2:The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

IIS on my development computer stopped working.  I just installed the latest update to windows 10 (1803) and now when I try to start the "Windows Process Activation Service" I get an "Windows could not start the Windows Process Activation Service on Local computer.  Error 2: The System cannot find the file specified" error.  Things I have already tried:

- Reinstalled IIS and Windows Process Activation Service, several times
- I verified that I do have a "C:\inetpub\temp\appPools" folder

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Run Process Monitor and then reproduce the error. You might be able to see some broken registry keys or files from the log. Reinstall Windows might be an easier fix.

Comment: I tried Process Monitor but it did not show anything of value.  I guess I am going to try the reinstall of Windows now.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have had this problem twice after a windows update. The issue seems to be, that windows adds an incorrect parameter to the WAS service startup parameters. I fixed the issue using the following steps:

- Start regedit (just type it into start)
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters
- Delete the NanoSetup variable. This variable is preventing WAS from starting
- Start the WAS service using task manager or by typing "net start WAS" in Command Prompt
- Start the W3SVC service the same way
- You can now start your website in IIS again

Comment: Ok Windows just did another major update to me and I got the same problem.  This time I followed you answer and this worked for me also.  I marked this as the accepted answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! My IIS could not start, the WAS service was also stopped and I could not get it to start. After removing the said variable, everything works as before the updates!

Comment: Thank you. this worked for me. Spent almost 2 days to find the fix

Comment: Wonderful. So easy, and completely resolved the issue.

Comment: According to [this thread on technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/315841e1-b8b2-4084-8224-580ef3d13420/upgrade-to-windows-10-1709-iis-fails?forum=win10itprosetup) the registry entry `NanoSetup` tells the service to perform some migration tasks (from a previous Windows version) on startup. Deleting the registry entry will have the service skip these migration tasks. You will find the actual error in the file `c:\windows\iis.log`.

Comment: So...you're telling me..I'd have never been able to start IIS unless I found this obscure piece of information about a leftover registry key from a bad windows update? And that's Microsoft's solution?

Comment: Just add apppools folder . C:\inetpub\temp\apppools. this works in my case.

Comment: Windows November 2019 update caused this problem and this DID NOT FIX IT. That key doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Triynko, Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @Hary you just need to follow Sascha answer

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and nothing in here was the solution for me for a long time. So i rolled back windows also. Today i found the solution working for me - Navigate to:

C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\

find these 3 Key-files...

d6d986f09a1ee04e24c949879fdb506c_*

76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_*

6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_*

... then in Security-Settings:

- first, you have to set your User as OWNER
- close Properties Dialog - and open again
- Then in ACL set "full controll" for SYSTEM

After that: WPA can be started...

Hope this helps; see also thread here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/315841e1-b8b2-4084-8224-580ef3d13420/upgrade-to-windows-10-1709-iis-fails?forum=win10itprosetup

Comment: genius! This allowed site to start in IIS! Thank you!

Comment: This fixes the problem with the November 2019 update.

Comment: This also fixed it for me.  Interesting to note that my error was 15 rather than 2 when starting the service.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem after installing the Windows 10 1909 update and the nanosetup variable was NOT in the registry. I ended up doing a variation of Sascha's fix.

I took ownership and gave administrators full control of the MachineKeys folder in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA. Then I removed the 3 files in Machinekeys that begin with:

d6d986f09a1ee04e24c949879fdb506c_*

76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_*

6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_*

The Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) started as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me after giving administrators permissions to all contents of the RSA folder.  I did not have to remove the 3 files mentioned, just changing permissions and ownership of the folder and its contents did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It just has a simple solution, you don't need to reinstall Windows or removing updates, It worked for me so sharing it with all of you,

1. if you already using IIS and have site's configurations and files in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config and C:\inetpub\wwwroot, Back up all files from the folder C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config and C:\inetpub\wwwroot, if you are installing ISS for the first time then you don't need to have a back up.
2. On Taskbar right-click on Start button select 'Run', type appwiz.cpl hit Enter.Click on 'Turn Windows features on or off'.
3. Uncheck 'Internet Information Services' and 'Windows Process Activation Service' click OK button.
4. After restarting Windows, Delete 'inetpub' folder on C: drive.
5. Open 'Turn Windows features on or off window' again.
6. Check 'Internet Information Services' and 'Windows Process Activation Service' click OK button.
7. After restarting Windows open folder C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config.
8. Right click on the file named 'applicationHost' Select Open with Notepad.
9. In Notepad, Copy all the content of the file.
10. Select New in File Menu and Paste all the content in the new file.
11. Save this file in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config with the name 'applicationHost.config.tmp', Don't forget choosing 'All Files' in the 'Save as type' box.
12. Otherwise, file will be saved as applicationHost.config.tmp.txt which will not work.
13. Type 'Services.msc' in Run, Find 'Windows Process Activation Service' in Services window.
14. Watch running the service successfully without any errors after clicking on start.

Comment: 14 utterly undocumented steps to get a basic windows feature working?  How did you arrive at these?

Comment: Man you saved my head from cracking... For others, first try step 13. If it didn't work then try other steps.

Comment: this is an outstanding solution which works without any flaws, not sure how it works, but saves you day

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to give up and rollback the windows build.  To do this follow these steps:

- Go to settings (Windows+I)
- Click on "Update & Security"
- On the left click on "Recovery"
- Then under "Go back to the previous version of Windows 10" click "Get
  started"

It rolled back to "1709" and now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself installing an application on a drive other than `C:` and that application relies on IIS, the path for inetpub temporary files may be missing. Even if they are present on `C:`, this may just confuse you into thinking they are present and thus not the issue.

Create the following empty directory structure, replacing `G:` with the drive letter that your application is installed to, other than `C:`.

```
G:\inetpub\temp\apppools
```

Then, start WAS, from an administrator command prompt:

```
net start WAS
```

If this has to do with IIS, restart for good measure, from the same prompt:

```
IISRESET /restart
```

This solved my problem when installing a third party application.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error after update, but on Windows Server 2022 Standard 21h2.
Tried all steps without success.
In my case WU deleted all params in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters
so i took it from old ControlSet002:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters]
"AccessDeniedMessage"="Error: Access is Denied."
"InstallPath"=hex(2):25,00,77,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,69,00,72,00,25,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,\
  73,00,72,00,76,00,00,00
"MajorVersion"=dword:0000000a
"MinorVersion"=dword:00000000
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,77,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,69,00,72,00,25,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,\
  73,00,72,00,76,00,5c,00,69,00,69,00,73,00,77,00,33,00,61,00,64,00,6d,00,2e,\
  00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
"GenerateKeys"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters\ListenerAdapters]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when reinstalling roles on our WSUS server, and it turned out to be a registry setting in my case.

Registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters

Change value of ***ConfigIsolation*** to  *(IISLocation)\inetpub\temp\appPools* path.

In this particular case we had previously moved IIS to a different drive, but when the role was removed the registry key apparently wasn't removed or updated. So when IIS was reinstalled I had to change the path from our custom IIS location back to the default.