# Process with an id of x is not running (Visual studio 2017)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, vs-web-site-project

**UPDATED BELOW**

I have went trough several (if not all) posts mentioning this error on SO and google, but still having this issue. The error I get is:

```
Process with an id of x is not running
```

In addition I can notice this error in my VS output window as well:

```
The program '[11392] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11392] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Where the number is always the same as the PID mentioned in the original error.

I have checked and no, the PID is not used by any process, I have done a ton of stuff like proposed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update), [here](https://www.ryadel.com/en/process-id-not-running-visual-studio-2015-fix/), [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029540/Solved-Process-With-An-Id-Of-Is-Not-Running), [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10937/process-with-an-id-of-1-is-not-running-when-i-try.html) and some others ...

This is for all my **Web projects** (newly created from scratch or old ones).
So with a WPF for example this is working fine.

So this must be something **IIS related** i think, uninstalled it, reinstalled it had not effect, neither did renaming/removing the IISEXPRESS folder in documents or checking all options in CPanel => Turn features on/off for the IIS options and tons of other things I tried like adding environment variable

> _CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKAROUNDS

run as admin, removing the .vs folder, removing the

> IISUrl , DevelopmentServerVPath & DevelopmentServerPort

parts in the .csproj file or checking the

> Tools menu > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects > Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express

even uninstalled all my VS versions and reinstalled only 1 VS Enterprise 2017 ...

**I'm completely lost here, what's happening?**
Any suggestion is welcome!

**UPDATE 1:**
I have uninstalled the IISExpress 10 and installed the version 8, still the same issue.

This is what Event viewer is logging:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          01/06/2019 09:33:00
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      PCName
Description:
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 8.0.8418.0, time  stamp: 0x4fbae3d6
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17763.475, time stamp:       0x3230aa04
Exception code: 0xc0000008
Fault offset: 0x00000000000a356a
Faulting process ID: 0x2d68
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5184c3d470917
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: cce33ecf-9507-42ab-87bf-9482a39181e9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-06-01T07:33:00.972839500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>58319</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>PCName</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>iisexpress.exe</Data>
    <Data>8.0.8418.0</Data>
    <Data>4fbae3d6</Data>
    <Data>ntdll.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.17763.475</Data>
    <Data>3230aa04</Data>
    <Data>c0000008</Data>
    <Data>00000000000a356a</Data>
    <Data>2d68</Data>
    <Data>01d5184c3d470917</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data>
    <Data>cce33ecf-9507-42ab-87bf-9482a39181e9</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I have tried running VS 2017 Enterprise in SafeMode and it gives me this error:
[image]

I will investigate this error further, please, if anyone has any idea, post it!

Comment: Does no one have any suggestions please? I can't go and re install Windows and just hope it will be fixed ...

Comment: Editted with latest update results.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Here are some of the things I've done that haven't worked:

1. Delete the `.vs` folder in my project
2. Delete the `IIS Express` folder in My Documents
3. Add `_CSRUN_DISABLE_WORKAROUNDS` to your environment variable
4. Restart the computer
5. Restart Visual Studio
6. Change the port
7. Even re-install visual studio
8. Uninstall IIS 10.0 Express via Control Panel, then reinstall

I've tried almost all the solutions I got from several forums and none of them have worked.

Finally I found the source of the problem. The source of the problem is not from my project nor from my visual studio, but from my IIS.

When I open `iisexpress.exe` from `C: \ Program Files \ IIS Express`, the command prompt closes immediately. If your IIS Express is fine, then what will appear is as shown below.

> [iisexpress.exe if success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsJaF.png)

What I do is reset or `reinstall IIS Express` via `Turn Windows Features on or off` in `Control Panel`. And follow the step by step contained in the following link

> [My worked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21036837)

This is the only way that worked for me, and hopefully it will help the others too.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was in different version of .net version on machine where i was trying to start project.
VS Solution was created on .net 6.o.5 version and after transferring solution to pc  where o.6.4 only installed - issue with process occurs.
After updating .net to correct version issue is gone.

P.S. method with deleting the .vs folder does not help.
P.S.2 VS2022