# The configuration section 'rewrite' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

**HTTP Error** 500.19 - Internal Server Error

**Error Code** 0x8007000d

**Config Error** The configuration section 'rewrite' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

**Config File** \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sad\web.config

**Config Source**

4 `<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
5 <rewrite>
6: <rules>`

Web.Config File;
http://i.hizliresim.com/Lp5mOa.png

Web.Config File txt; http://tema.biz/web.config.txt

Comment: Is URL Rewrite installed on the web server? If not, you can install it from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Comment: Thanks next error,
"Configuration file is not well-formed XML"

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20099454/2835243) and tell me if it works